# Counting based on group of 1st column

Tags: sql

I am using following query to count how many Bill_date each BAN have

```
select replace(c.usertoken, '-', '') as BAN
       , to_char(to_date(bi.name,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'dd-mm-yy') as Billdate_dmy
       , (replace(c.usertoken, '-', '') ||':'|| to_char(to_date(bi.name,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'dd-mm-yy')) as BAN_Billdate_dmy
       , count(c.usertoken) as Number_Of_Bills
from customer c
     , service s
     , document d
     , bill bi
     , batch ba
     , billrun br
where c.ID = s.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID 
and s.ID = d.SERVICE_DOCUMENT_ID 
and bi.ID = d.BILL_DOCUMENT_ID 
and d.BATCH = ba.ID 
and ba.BILLRUN = br.ID 
and br.STATUS = 'APPROVED' 
and c.brand='rogers' 
and d.VERSIONEDCONTENTFOLDER='cbu'
group by c.usertoken, bi.name
order by c.usertoken
```

Output of the above query

```
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------+--+-------+
|    BAN    | Bill_date | BAN_Billdate      |        Count |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------+--+-------+
| 100001247 | 25-09-19 | 100001247:25-09-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100001247 | 25-10-19 | 100001247:25-10-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100002583 | 15-10-19 | 100002583:15-10-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100004753 | 25-09-19 | 100004753:25-09-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100004753 | 25-10-19 | 100004753:25-10-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100005719 | 25-09-19 | 100005719:25-09-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100005719 | 25-10-19 | 100005719:25-10-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100006311 | 06-09-19 | 100006311:06-09-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100009596 | 25-09-19 | 100009596:25-09-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100009596 | 25-10-19 | 100009596:25-10-19 |            1 |  |       |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------+--+-------+
```

However I was expecting the following output

```
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------+--+-------+
|    BAN    | Billdate |   BAN_Billdate |  |          Count |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------+--+-------+
| 100001247 | 25-09-19 | 100001247:25-09-19 |            2 |  |       |
| 100001247 | 25-10-19 | 100001247:25-10-19 |            2 |  |       |
| 100002583 | 15-10-19 | 100002583:15-10-19 |            3 |  |       |
| 100004753 | 25-09-19 | 100004753:25-09-19 |            3 |  |       |
| 100004753 | 25-10-19 | 100004753:25-10-19 |            3 |  |       |
| 100005719 | 25-09-19 | 100005719:25-09-19 |            2 |  |       |
| 100005719 | 25-10-19 | 100005719:25-10-19 |            2 |  |       |
| 100006311 | 06-09-19 | 100006311:06-09-19 |            1 |  |       |
| 100009596 | 25-09-19 | 100009596:25-09-19 |            2 |  |       |
| 100009596 | 25-10-19 | 100009596:25-10-19 |            2 |  |       |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------------+--+-------+
```

Please advise what changes should I do in the query to have the count column reflecting the expected values.

Comment: mysql <> sql-server and your functions point to oracle / plsql. Which RDMS are you using? Also, your results have columns names that aren't in your query. Where is the column `Number_Of_Bills`? Regardless, we need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please take a moment and [read how to ask a good SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: You could try `count(*)`

Comment: @avery_larry he did that but how did he done it is the question :)

Comment: @pradeep please can you explain why do you have `| 100002583 | 15-10-19 | 100002583:15-10-19 |            3 |  |       |` this line in your result when there is only one 100002583  ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBokšić What?  The OP's query clearly has `count(c.usertoken)`, which is not the same as `count(*)`.  Though it probably should be `count(*) over (partition by replace(c.usertoken, '-', '')` which I don't know if that works in whatever database product is being used.

Comment: I aimed towards usage(way how OP is using the count), like, he is using **count** (not looking what is inside of the brackets) but he is using it in a wrong way. Yes, I believe the `count(*) over (partition by replace(c.usertoken, '-', '')` would do it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to touch your query and the archaic `join` syntax.  Please learn proper SQL grammar with `JOIN` and `ON` clauses for joins.

That said, you seem to want a window function to sum the counts:

```
select sum(count(*)) over (partition by ban, to_date(bi.name, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

I'm not sure that aggregation is really useful, if you are only getting one row per group.  In that case, you might want to remove the `group by` and use:

```
select count(*) over (partition by ban, to_date(bi.name, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```